# print carriage return (not line feed) in erlang?

Tags: erlang

Wondering if it's possible to print a carriage return without a line feed in erlang?  i.e. equivalent to `printf("this will be replaced next time \r");` in C.

Had a look through the [io:format()](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html) documentation and didn't see anything.  It only seems to support ~n, equivalent to carriage return+line feed pair ('\n' in C).

Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"\r" is a perfectly valid escape sequence in Erlang. So you can do just

```
io:format("\r").
```

Check the [reference manual](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id63679) for other escape sequences.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\r` in a string for the return character so:

```
io:format("Counter value: ~b\r", [Counter])
```

This is also works for character constants, `$\r`, and in quoted atoms.

Comment: Thanks for response.  Hadn't realised erlang supported escape sequences as well as interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Doh.  Answer came almost as soon as I posted.  `~c` enables printing of ASCII characters, so it's just a case of printing ASCII carriage return (13).  e.g.

```
io:format("Counter value: ~b~c", [Counter,13])
```

Still interested in anything more elegant...

Thx.